# JavaScript-JQuery : Difference between onSubmit and .submit()

Tags: javascript, jquery

Since a few days, I had a problem with a javascript process.
In fact, In a page the user can add et delete "skills". This process is realised with Javascript.

**So when the user confirm the suppression of a skill with this form :**

```
<form onsubmit="return submitFormsupprCompetence(this,'skill');" method="POST">
    ...
    <input name="confirmSupprCompetence" id="confirmSupprSkill" type="submit" value="Confirm">
</form>
```

**The function 'submitFormSupprCompetence(form,skill)' is called :**

```
function supprCompetence_mafiche(form_serialize,skill){
    var data = {
          "formulaire": form_serialize,
          "skill": skill,
    };

    $.ajax({
        'type' : 'POST',
        'dataType' : 'json',
        'url' : "/supprSkill",
        'data': data,

        success: function(json){
                // I detach the div of skill :
                $("#skill").detach();       
                // I load the div containing all div (id='theskills') of skill      
                $('#theskills').load(document.URL +  ' #theskills');             
        },
        error:function(data){
            alert("Error in Suppression");
        }
}); 

return false;
}
```

**So the suppression works** 
BUT immediately after suppression, the user can't add a skill without refresh the page. It's the case when I use this :

```
<form id="formAddSkill" method="POST">

$(document).ready(function() {
    $("#formAddSkill").submit(function(evt) {
        evt.preventDefault();
        addSkill();
        return false;
    });
});
```

**But the adding after suppression works when I call the adding function directly in 'onsubmit' :**

```
<form onsubmit="addSkill();return false;" id="formAddSkill" method="POST">
```

**Quickly the adding function 'addSkill()' is :**

```
function addSkill(){    
    var data = {
          "skill": "skill_lambda",
        };

    $.ajax({
      'type' : 'POST',
      'dataType' : 'json',
      'url' : "/addSkill",
      'data': data,

      success: function(json){  
         // I load the div containing all div (id='theskills') of skill like in suppression form :  
        $('#theskills').load(document.URL +  ' #theskills');       
        },
      error:function(data){
        alert("Error in adding...");
        }
    }); 
}         
return false;
}
```

**So, why when the skill adding directly after suppression works when I use** `onsubmit=...` **and not when I use the JQuery function** `$(document).ready(function(){ $("#formAddSkill").submit(function(evt)...` **?**

Comment: Please before doing this type of question first google or standard of stackoverflow will be spoiled visit here. http://goo.gl/Jt9aLX

Comment: So I know the difference between form onsubmit and submit button click but I don't understand why this difference is important in my process... It's the reason of my post :/